# PGF and TikZ - dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been using LaTeX to write up a report involving MATLAB-code. To display the graphs, I have been using [matlab2tikz](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz). Now, here is my problem;

My MATLAB generated plot looks like this:

[image: plot]

The TeX code generated by matlab2tikz looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=11.411cm,
height=8cm,
at={(0cm,0cm)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-3.5,
xmax=0,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00363510693504221,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
-3.1    7.84480748378651e-05\\
-3.09624530663329   3.3346096155051e-05\\
-3.0927770900083    2.77555756156289e-17\\
-3.09249061326658   2.42735718568657e-06\\
-3.08873591989987   3.00232213960843e-05\\
-3.08498122653317   5.04933057718943e-05\\

.
.
.

-0.137546933667084  0.00127033315837011\\
-0.133792240300376  0.00139138385307547\\
-0.130037546933667  0.00147074815075676\\
-0.126282853566959  0.00149417736539847\\
-0.12252816020025   0.00144467572293849\\
-0.118773466833542  0.00130203824456698\\
-0.115018773466834  0.00104230702841579\\
-0.111264080100125  0.000637129320870899\\
-0.107509386733417  5.29967618541072e-05\\
-0.107222909991705  6.66133814775094e-16\\
-0.103754693366708  0.000749659959249138\\
-0.1    0.0018175534675211\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.001708984375  1.001708984375\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

When building the script, I get the following error:

> Dimension too large. \endaxis

Where does the error come from and how can I adjust my code in order to fix this specific problem?

Comment: It's the last `\addplot` it only has one point and gets interfered with something I guess `xmax=0`

Comment: Thank you, removing the last \addplot fixed it. I have no idea where it comes from though. I guess I'll redirect my question to another stackexchange then!

Comment: To understand where that comes from, we'd probably need to see the Matlab code that generated the plot, but as you say, then it starts becoming off topic for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because determined not to be about TeX (see comment posted as answer by OP).

Comment: This question led me to the solution when I was having a similar issue. I use out-of-bounds single-data-point plots to build my legend when I am plotting a lot of various data. I use the colour to distinguish various data sets, use solid lines for model data, and symbols for measured data. Different sources for measurement data are assigned different symbols, so circles are data from source X and triangles data from source Y. In the legend, I plot black symbols (a color which I don't use for the data sets) to denote: "circles represent data from X". These black symbols are plotted off figure.

Comment: ... continued: if the off-figure location is too far outside the range specified with xmin/xmax and ymin/ymax, I get a "Dimension too large" error. In this case, removing the offending `\addplot` command is no solution, since I need it for the legend, however, by ensuring that no value-pair of any `\addplot` command lies too far outside the visible range, having off-figure data points should pose no problems.

Answer (score 1):

As @percusse pointed out with his comment, this has a rather trivial answer. I guess this is due to the matlab2tikz script and therefore doesn't really belong in the tex.stackexhange.